# localhost redirects me to another url

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, xampp

I am working on a website with wordpress locally. I have a project that when I run it in firefox or chrome it redirects me to another site that I also have on localhost.
Example: I want to open

> localhost/new-project

but it automatically redirects me to

> localhost/old-project

I already tried the following:

- modify siteurl and home from wp_options in phpMyAdmin
- modify the urls from the wordpress panel
- check the SITE_URL in wp-config

All of the above is correct. I don't know what else to do to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Just close the active port in which the old project is running than try.